# Someone is downvoting my answers here every day since about one month

Tags: support, status-completed, down-votes

I'm receiving downvotes pretty much every day, sometimes more than once per day on a wide range of answers without any correlation about the topic and the details of my argument. Perhaps others here have experienced this too. I'm not sure why someone would do this. I'm thinking that it could be Trump as he's likely to be bored due to not being allowed to post on Twitter and Facebook...

Comment: I *highly* doubt that Donald Trump is behind this, but if you're being serially downvoted, there's an algorithm that should catch the downvotes and reverse them.

Comment: Interestingly that this post has two downvotes... Whoever is doing this might be using more than one account for such purposes as well. (Ok, maybe someone didn't like your Trump pun; maybe you should remove that.)

Comment: Since you post very seldom here on Politics nowadays I'm guessing it's more likely someone with whom you've had a disagreement on some other SE site... Unless someone held a grudge for years and only decided to act now, which seems a bit implausible.

Comment: I just downvoted your meta question just because the mention of Trump is gratuitous and makes it hard to take your complaint seriously, especially because it's not clear from your question what you want anyone to do about it.

Comment: FYI: I've been subject to this behavior as well, though not on this scale (and it's not really something I care about in any case). But just so you don't feel it's *overly* personal. Trolls are gonna troll, troll, troll, troll, troll... (apologies to TayTay).

Answer (score 15):

It indeed appears that you are the victim of rather unusual downvoting activity. It appears that over the past month, someone downvoted exactly one post of yours per day. Among those downvoted posts are posts made *years* ago. This pattern indeed looks like a [revenge downvoting campaign](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed), stretched out to one vote per day in an attempt to avoid triggering any of the automatic saveguards against voting fraud.

As this is a public forum, I am not at liberty to say much more about who is the most likely culprit, how exactly we know that and what actions we are going to take in this matter. But I think it doesn't hurt if I say that none of the prime suspects appear to use IP addresses from Palm Beach, Florida.

Comment: You can see users IP addresses?

Comment: @EkadhSingh yes, see [this post on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149637).

Comment: "As this is a public forum, I am not at liberty to say much more about who is the most likely culprit and what actions we are going to take in this matter.": why not be transparent about it?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt because votes are [anonymous by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12985).

Comment: @JJJ but I'm guessing that in order to take action, you have to go through some SE employee, who can see the username of the repeated offender, right?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt yes they are [able to see the votes, except for votes cast on their own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90758). As for this (or any) specific case, I don't think it should be hashed out in public (or even between the parties in conflict). If someone went too far then they will face some consequences (warning / suspension) and the damage will be undone (votes reversed). Then that's it, see also [this meta Q](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293213) for some background on the suspension system and publicity.

Answer (score 10):

This episode of targeted downvoting has now been resolved, and the offending votes invalidated. Thank you for bearing with us and the Community Management team while this was properly investigated.

Answer (score 4):

I think this ought to be automatically caught, so I opened a request: [Improve the detection of targetted downvoting (failed to catch someone downvoting a user almost daily for a month)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364011/178179).